# Why i see "null" in dato2 to return of my second activity?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to practice launching there activity for passing values ​​both in and out, but I don't understand how to solve this return value drawback as a string.

This is my second activity that need to return a string, but i see "null" in toast.

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity {

public String stringa = "Ciao";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity1);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Log.d("GETINTENT", "prende dato1");
    int i = 3;
    int dato1 = intent.getIntExtra("x", i);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Intero Main: "+ dato1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    setReturnIntent();
}

public void setReturnIntent() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("STRINGA",stringa);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
    Log.d("LANCIO","lancio con setResult");
    finish();
}
```

This is my main code on Android Studio when i put a int and i see in toast

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public int x = 5;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void lanciaActivity(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this,Activity1.class);
    i.putExtra("x", x);
    startActivityForResult(i,0);
    Log.d("LANCIOST","Lancio con startActivityForR");
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode != 0) return;
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) return;
    if (data == null) return;
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Log.d("GETSTRING", "Preso dato2");
    String dato2 = intent.getStringExtra("STRINGA");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stringa: "+ dato2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

Comment: please don't post code as images

Comment: I noticed that putting a toast with the intent of the intent.putextra variable, the printing is done correctly; the problem is in the main that it does not pass the value of the string

Comment: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60073388/edit) your question to include your code as text inside your question, instead of linking to off-site images please :)

Answer (score 0):

i see your first activity code you use inten.getStringExtra() to get the data use the `data.getStringExtra` to get the data from second activity into activityResult..

Comment: Thank you very much for your help; now it's ok.